# Xcode allocations instrument generations

Tags: ios, memory, allocation, xcode-instruments

I've been using Instruments on an ARC project (run on a device) to make sure I'm cleaning up any abandoned memory.  To this end, I've been using the allocations generations tool and taking snapshots of my heap for the same action 10-20 times.  What I'm confused about is the growth.  Some of the time the growth is 0, and then the other, some number of bytes (never consistent ranging from a few bytes to a several kilobytes) seems to be accruing.  But there is usually at least few iterations where the growth is 0.

My question is: if my growth is sometimes 0, does that mean that my memory management is correct?  Or do  I still have issues that I need to ferret out?  I understand that it might take several cycles for the memory to "drain", but what about the memory that is still being allocated and remaining even after >10 iterations?

This seems like a more general question about the interpretation of Instruments, so I've left out any specific code.  Besides, I've found this happening in various heap snapshot scenarios: pull to refresh, push view controller, etc.

Edit: I've included a [snapshot of my Instruments window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gBDA.png).

Comment: You should look for Memory Leaks than Allocations. You can allocate some object, use it, and release it once done, so there is an allocation counted, but no issue.

Comment: I always keep Memory Leaks as a view alongside Allocations and none ever pop up.  But from what I understand you still can have leaks that are not caught by Instruments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that if you have several iterations of your action loop that result in 0 bytes allocated and still living then you are good on memory management and have no leaks.

The increases you are seeing (from a few bytes to a few kilobytes) are most likely from the OS or background Apple code doing things to try to manage the tasks you are doing.  One easy example is if you bring up the keyboard for the first time Apple allocats memory for it that is never released, so that iteration you will see "leaked" memory that you didn't create.  Everything you do has background code that Apple runs and you can't define what it wants to do with memory.  It could be cacheing specific things that are done often so that next time it runs faster.  The whole Apple philosophy is smooth running apps so the user experience is the best it can be.  What the OS does in the background to make that happen can be intermittent and can cause unreleased memory.

Check the heap-snapshots for what objects were allocated and not released.  If you can track those objects to your code then fix it, if you can't then it's likely an OS allocation that either can or cannot be avoided.  Like I said a moment ago, if you are getting a lot of 0 increases then I would not worry about it because of these intermittent OS increases.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Putz1103.  Then does that mean that if I get, say 1 0-growth iteration per 5 positive-growth iterations that I probably have an issue? (i.e. the majority of the heap snapshots have growth).

Comment: I found this comment from cocoabuilder from b.bum in: [heapshot analysis to find Memory Leaks](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/294532-heapshot-analysis-to-find-memory-accretion-leaks.html):

"In general, what you are looking for is any iteration with ZERO allocations.  If you see even one iteration -- one heapshot sample -- with zero allocations, it means that the code that you are directly testing (in this case, new document, close document) **does not directly cause any permanent allocations**."

Comment: So it sounds like the general consensus (or at least based on 2 people) that have even a small amount of zero-growth iterations means that you are doing ok memory-wise.  I'm good with that.

Comment: That is what I have come to understand in my testing.  Whether I'm right or wrong is a valid question.

Comment: Understood.  But I appreciate the insight of experience.  Hopefully as I continue to develop apps the patterns of Instruments will become more apparent to me.